# Проблема с VM-FEX (Cisco UCS Hardware VN-Link)

Tags: vmware, cisco

Добрый день, коллеги!

Дано:

```
Есть 3 сервера: 2 B200M3 и 1 UCSC-C240-M3S с карточками Cisco UCS VIC 1240 и   VIC 1225 соответственно.

 . На них развернуты ESXi: 

Product: VMware ESXi
Version: 6.0.0
Build: Releasebuild-3825889
Update: 2
Patch: 37
```

Vcenter - Windows Base Host. Сначала стоял VCSA, но после прочтения вот [этого](https://bst.cloudapps.cisco.com/bugsearch/bug/CSCur36773/?referring_site=bugquickviewredir)- перевел все на Windows.

```
Для тех у кого нет аккаунта на Cisco:
Add support of vCenter Server Appliance and VM-FEX
CSCur36773
Description
Symptom:
Enhancement request to QA/support vCenter Server Appliance and VM-FEX

Currently VM-FEX and vCSA are not supported and require the full install of vCenter on Windows. Customers are starting to migrate to vCSA for cost and simplicity purposes.

From VMware:
"UCS Manager with VM-FEX does not support the vCenter Server Appliance in any available release."

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2004079

From Cisco:
"You need VMware vCenter (vCenter Server and vSphere Client) for VM-FEX for VMware. The VMware vCenter must meet the following requirements:

The Windows-based machine that you install VMware vCenter on must have network connectivity to the Cisco UCS management port and to the uplink Ethernet port(s) being used by the ESX host."

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/unified_computing/ucs/sw/vm_fex/vmware/gui/config_guide/2-2/b_GUI_VMware_VM-FEX_UCSM_Configuration_Guide_2_2/b_GUI_VMware_VM-FEX_UCSM_Configuration_Guide_2_2_1_chapter_01.html

Conditions:
N/A

Workaround:
N/A

2 FI:UCS-LABO - Unified Computing System -->

UCS-FI-6248UP
Cisco UCSM 3.1(1g)
```

При настройке VM-FEX возникли проблемы. На Vcenter зарегистрировал плагин, провел интеграцию. На UCS создал Template c Dynamic vNIC Policy. Из него сделал Service Profile и прилепил к серверам.

Вообщем, все настроил в соответствии с официальной [документацией](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/unified_computing/ucs/sw/vm_fex/vmware/gui/config_guide/2-2/b_GUI_VMware_VM-FEX_UCSM_Configuration_Guide_2_2/b_GUI_VMware_VM-FEX_UCSM_Configuration_Guide_2_2_1_chapter_011.html).

#

```
UCS-LABO-B /org/service-profile # show

Service Profile:
Service Profile Name Type Server Assignment Association
-------------------- ----------------- ------- ---------- -----------
ASTEL-JSC/BLADE-SERVERS1
Instance 1/1 Assigned Associated
```

#

```
UCS-LABO-B /org/service-profile # show service-profile circuit server 1/1 
Service Profile: ASTEL-JSC/BLADE-SERVERS1
Server: 1/1
Fabric ID: A
Path ID: 1
VIF vNIC Link State Oper State Prot State Prot Role Admin Pin Oper Pin Transport
---------- --------------- ----------- ---------- ------------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------

10080 Up Active No Protection Unprotected 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
1880 A1 Up Active Active Primary 0/0/0 0/0/1 Ether
1883 B1 Up Active Passive Backup 0/0/0 0/0/1 Ether
1884 A2 Up Active Active Primary 0/0/0 0/0/1 Ether
1887 B2 Up Active Passive Backup 0/0/0 0/0/1 Ether
1888 vHBA-A Up Active No Protection Unprotected 0/0/0 0/0/0 Fc
1986 dynamic-prot-001
Unknown Unknown No Protection Primary 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
1989 dynamic-prot-002
Unknown Unknown No Protection Backup 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
1990 dynamic-prot-003
Unknown Unknown No Protection Primary 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
1993 dynamic-prot-004
Unknown Unknown No Protection Backup 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
1994 dynamic-prot-005
Unknown Unknown No Protection Primary 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
1997 dynamic-prot-006
Unknown Unknown No Protection Backup 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
1998 dynamic-prot-007
Unknown Unknown No Protection Primary 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
2001 dynamic-prot-008
Unknown Unknown No Protection Backup 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
2002 dynamic-prot-009
Unknown Unknown No Protection Primary 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
2005 dynamic-prot-010
Unknown Unknown No Protection Backup 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
Fabric ID: B
Path ID: 1
VIF vNIC Link State Oper State Prot State Prot Role Admin Pin Oper Pin Transport
```

---

```
10081 Up Active No Protection Unprotected 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
1881 A1 Up Active Passive Backup 0/0/0 0/0/1 Ether
1882 B1 Up Active Active Primary 0/0/0 0/0/1 Ether
1885 A2 Up Active Passive Backup 0/0/0 0/0/1 Ether
1886 B2 Up Active Active Primary 0/0/0 0/0/1 Ether
1889 vHBA-B Up Active No Protection Unprotected 0/0/0 0/0/0 Fc
1987 dynamic-prot-001
Unknown Unknown No Protection Backup 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
1988 dynamic-prot-002
Unknown Unknown No Protection Primary 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
1991 dynamic-prot-003
Unknown Unknown No Protection Backup 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
1992 dynamic-prot-004
Unknown Unknown No Protection Primary 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
1995 dynamic-prot-005
Unknown Unknown No Protection Backup 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
1996 dynamic-prot-006
Unknown Unknown No Protection Primary 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
1999 dynamic-prot-007
Unknown Unknown No Protection Backup 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
2000 dynamic-prot-008
Unknown Unknown No Protection Primary 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
2003 dynamic-prot-009
Unknown Unknown No Protection Backup 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether
2004 dynamic-prot-010
Unknown Unknown No Protection Primary 0/0/0 0/0/0 Ether

################################################

UCS-LABO-B /org/service-profile # show dynamic-vnic-conn-policy detail

Dynamic vNIC Connectivity Policy:
Name: ASTEL-JSC/VM-FEX
Dynamic Eth: 10
Adapter Policy: SRIOV
Protection: Protected
Description: Dynamic vNIC Policy for VM-FEX
Policy Owner: Local

#################################################

UCS-LABO-B /org/service-profile # show vnic connectivity

vNIC:

Name Dynamic MAC Addr Type Fabric ID
---------- ---------------- ------- ---------
A1 00:25:B5:00:00:8F Ether A B
A2 00:25:B5:00:00:6F Ether A B
B1 00:25:B5:00:00:9F Ether B A
B2 00:25:B5:00:00:7F Ether B A
dynamic-prot-001 Derived Ether A B
dynamic-prot-002 Derived Ether B A
dynamic-prot-003 Derived Ether A B
dynamic-prot-004 Derived Ether B A
dynamic-prot-005 Derived Ether A B
dynamic-prot-006 Derived Ether B A
dynamic-prot-007 Derived Ether A B
dynamic-prot-008 Derived Ether B A
dynamic-prot-009 Derived Ether A B
dynamic-prot-010 Derived Ether B A

vHBA:

Name Dynamic WWPN Type Fabric ID
---------- ------------ ------- ---------
vHBA-A 20:00:00:25:B5:00:0A:4F Fc A
vHBA-B 20:00:00:25:B5:00:0B:4F Fc B

############################################

UCS-LABO-B /system/vm-mgmt/vm-life-cycle-policy # show

VM Life Cycle Policy:
VM Retention Time (Minutes) vNIC Retention Time (Minutes)
--------------------------- -----------------------------
1 Day 1 Day

################################################

UCS-LABO-B /system/vm-mgmt/vmware # show vcenter

vCenter:
Name: alm-vc02
Description: Vmware Vcenter for Cisco UCS LAB
Hostname or IP address: 192.168.93.253
Port number: Default
Certificate:
vCenter Server Version: VMware vCenter Server 6.0.0 build-3018524

Name: alm-vcsa01
Description:
Hostname or IP address: 192.168.93.254
Port number: Default
Certificate:
vCenter Server Version: VMware vCenter Server 6.0.0 build-3018523
```

#

UCS-LABO-B /system/vm-mgmt/vmware # show extension-key

Extension Key:

### Key

Cisco-UCSM-be049a90-adeb-11e5-8f9

#

```
С самого начала смущает вот это:

UCS-LABO-B /system/vm-mgmt/vmware # show profile-set fsm status


FSM 1:
Remote Result: Not Applicable
Remote Error Code: None
Remote Error Description:
Status: Nop
Previous Status: Deploy Success
Timestamp: 2016-06-02T23:46:10.320
Try: 0
Progress (%): 100
Current Task:
```

#

После настройки dSW, Port Profile и Client Profile на UCS, создался dSW на Vcenter с порт группами соответствующими. Туда я добавил 2 статических NIC - как аплинки.

Единственное что меня насторожило так это раздел в официальной документации по инсталляции VEM модуля.

Я как ни старался и сколько не скачивал ISO Drivers Bundle, ни в одном из них не обнаружил VIB пакета для свитча.

You must obtain the Cisco VM-FEX Driver software bundle from the Cisco Download Software page:

For B-Series from, http:/​/​software.cisco.com/​download/​navigator.html. Select Downloads Home > Products >Servers - Unified Computing > Cisco UCS B-Series Blade Server Software and click Unified Computing Systems (UCS) Drivers. From this page, click Latest Releases or All Releases to select the release you want, and clickDownload to download the ISO image of UCS-related drivers.

```
Посему при инсталляции я использовал следующий пакет.

[root@ucs-1-1:~] vem status -v
Package vssnet-esxesx2015-release
Version 5.2.1.3.1.15.0-6.0.1
Build 1
Date Sun Feb 21 12:20:37 PST 2016

VEM modules are loaded

DVS Name Num Ports Used Ports Configured Ports MTU Uplinks 
UCS-LAB-dSW 3072 8 512 1500 vmnic1,vmnic0
DVS Name Num Ports Used Ports Configured Ports MTU Uplinks 
VM-FEX 256 15 256 1500 vmnic3,vmnic2

VEM Agent (vemdpa) is running
```

#

Однако, здесь же, на саппорт коммьюнити я наткнулся на обсуждение очень похожее с моей ситуацией, к сожалению, не могу его найти, где автор сказал следующее:

```
Yes, initially we used to have the same file for both the N1k and VM-FEX but this was changed sometime back. A good way to check this would be to see what VEM modules are loaded. For example:

N1k:

~ # esxcfg-module -l | grep vem
vem-v160-l2device 3 36
vem-v160-n1kv 13 220
vem-v160-vssnet 4 6820
vem-v160-stun 1 128


VM-FEX:
~ # esxcfg-module -l | grep vem
vem-v152-vmfex-svs-mux 11 32
vem-v152-vmfex-pts 1 148
The version number (v160, v152) could vary, but the modules PTS, svs-mux etc won't change.

VM-FEX and N1KV are mutually exclusive 

    Both of these options create VDS on the hypervisor. You wouldn't run multiple VDS on the same
    host.
        VM-FEX and N1KV both use VEM's
        N1KV uses the VSM for the Control Plane
        VM-FEX uses the UCS FI's as it's Control Plane
```

Это как раз моя ситуация. У меня как раз не видно модуля PTS. Как я понимаю VEM модуль должен работать в другом "режиме"
если увидит dynamiv-vnic со стороны сервера. Но как этого добиться я ума не приложу.
В моем все порты которые принадлежат моему VM-FEX, вернее порты VM которые помещены на этот dSW являются заблокированными, см. приложенный файл.
Буду рад любым комментариям и подсказкам которые могут послужить ориентиром для дальнейших поисков проблемы.
Спасибо.